# Banking Applications need Auto save?

Tags: java, performance

We are developing a banking application. It's internal project of the bank. The application has to capture huge data to process.

So auto save is recommended approach to capture? How to perform validations in case of auto save?

And on jsp unload saving the data is correct approach?

Which is best way of saving form data in case of auto save? If any network errors occur, how to handle, mean giving end user the data is not saved? I think it's just a feasible solution. Please suggest me optimal solution.

Comment: What kind of application are you talking about? If you are talking about 'auto save' a UI with user input comes to my mind. But then I wonder where the 'huge data' is supposed to come from. I'd say you should be a bit more explicit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data capture + high data volume + web application + performance == FAIL
Sorry, but you will have to seriously rethink the planned solution route to your homework assignment.
Think client-server instead.